# How to round figure of sum value

Tags: php, sum

How to round figure of echo sum value

```
<?php echo (90+10)*15*732/365/30 ;   ?>
```

this code showing like this

> 100.27397260274

and I want like this

> 100.300

and I am using like this but this is also not working

```
<?php echo ((round((90+10)*15*732/365/30, 1)),3) ;   ?>
```

how can I do this?

Comment: That question is a bit absurd. The 100.027 would roll to maybe 100.03 but not 100.300...This is not how roll works with Mathematics.

Comment: this code is not showing proper answser thats why it is showing like 100.027 but correct answer is 100.27397 and i want like that 100.300

Comment: ok now im using this   <?php echo (90+10)*15*732/365/30 ;   ?> and now my answer is 100.27397260274 and i want round figure of value 100.300 how can i do this

Comment: because you are missing the BODMAS..

Comment: see my qustion i update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
<?php echo round( (90+10)*15*732/365/30 , 2 ); ?>
```

and the output will be:

> 100.27

and for `100.3` you can do

```
<?php echo round( (90+10)*15*732/365/30,1 ); ?>
```

and for `100.300` you need to use extra function [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format) with the `3` for the value of decimals:

```
<?php echo number_format( round((90+10)*15*732/365/30,1), 3 ); ?>
```

Comment: i want like that 100.300 after 100 3 value

Comment: Using `printf` you don't need to use an extra function. (btw, wasn't me who downvoted you)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
round(number,decimal_place);
```